How to replace EC2 root volume with snapshot that has been attached to the instance in the future
I have an EC2 instance with a root volume (/dev/xvda1) and a device attached that is not root (/dev/xvdh1), but which is mounted to root:
$ sudo lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
xvda    202:0    0   200G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   200G  0 part 
xvdh    202:112  0   200G  0 disk 
└─xvdh1 202:113  0   200G  0 part /

I would like to replace the root volume with the device attached that is not root.
I made a snapshot of the device that has the data I want (/dev/xvdh1), and then I attempted to replace the root volume (/dev/xvda1) with that snapshot, which yielded the following error message:
% aws ec2 create-replace-root-volume-task --instance-id i-foobarbaz --snapshot-id snap-foobarbaz --no-delete-replaced-root-volume

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateReplaceRootVolumeTask operation: Invalid snapshot for root volume for virt i-foobarbaz. The snapshot should be of one of the root volumes attached to the instance in the past

Ultimately, I would like to replace the contents of /dev/xvda1 entirely with what is on /dev/xvdh1 and then detach /dev/xvdh1 so that I can have this host running off the root volume with the files I need, without paying for both xvda1 and xvdh1.
What should I do to accomplish this, which sidesteps or otherwise resolves this error message?

Before doing anything I would first create a new AMI from the current instance as a precautionary step.
Since you already have the snapshot of the data you need, you can create a new volume based on that snapshot.
Create a new volume from the snapshot you took of /dev/xvdh1:
aws ec2 create-volume --availability-zone <instance-az> --snapshot-id snap-foobarbaz --volume-type gp3 --size 200

Attach this newly created volume to the instance as a temporary volume (e.g., /dev/sdf or another unused device name).
aws ec2 attach-volume --instance-id i-foobarbaz --volume-id vol-<new-volume-id> --device /dev/sdf

Then, stop the instance and detach the root volume (/dev/xvdh1). Now, reattach the volume you created from the snapshot as the root device (/dev/xvda).
It might also be necessary to modify the boot config if the EC2 instance does not boot after this change. You will need to update fstab file or reinstall the bootloader.
